# Fill line with asterisks

Tags: loops, text-manipulation

I want to fill a line with asterisks just like as with `\cdots` or `\ldots` that can be used in tables, `\leaders` solution doesn't work well.

I'm working in a fixed columns width table, where at the end of the data it is fill with asterisk to denote the end of data.

this what i get inserting asterisks manually and using a command base on \leaders:
[image]

As is shown in the picture the \leaders way do not fill well the column

Comment: Can you make an example of use? And where do `\leaders` fail?

Comment: "doesn't work well" is not really informative; I added to my answer one example using `\leaders` inside a table and I didn't see a problem. Add to your question some example *code* showing the real context in which you need the asteriks and why `\leaders` fails.

Comment: Ah, you should use `\hfill` and not `\hfil`. **If you constructed a proper MWE, it would have taken 30 seconds to give you this answer.**

Comment: Did you try using the command in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\leaders`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\asteriskfill{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{$\ast$}\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\asteriskfill

Some reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Using something like

```
\newcommand\asteriskfill{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{$\ast\ $}\hfill\kern0pt}
```

will space out the asterisks.

Inside a `tabular`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\asteriskfill{\leavevmode\xleaders\hbox{$\ast\ $}\hfill\kern0pt}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\asteriskfill

Some reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text reference text\par\bigskip

\noindent
\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}p{5cm}}
\hline
column1 & column2 \\
\asteriskfill & \asteriskfill \\
column1 & column2 \\
\asteriskfill & \asteriskfill \\
column1 & column2 \\
\asteriskfill & \asteriskfill \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: O.k. thanks your code is almost the same as what i was trying to do : yours $\ast\ $ mine $\ast$ . Yours looks better. But I discover that what really was happening to me is that \leaders seems to does not work well with a package i was loading "colortbl". Afeter i ended loading it all works great